# Why is boost::asio::io_context::run() still blocking after boost::beast::websocket::stream::close()?

Tags: boost, websocket, concurrency, asio, beast

I have a pool of threads using concurrently the same `io_context` to run a websocket stream.
I am doing this because first, I have actually 2 websocket streams (I abstracted this because by testing it appears not to be the problem), and because I want to run other io operations aside the websocket ones, which are namely `async_read` and `async_write`.

Each websocket stream is using its own strand and additional locking is used to ensure that a `async_read` (resp. `async_write`) is not performed before another one reached the handler.

So basically:

```
io_context context;
std::vector<std::thread> pool(std::thread::hardware_concurrency());
...
wss(make_strand(context),ssl);
...
wss.async_read(&loop_read_handler);
...
for(auto& th:pool)
    th=std::thread([&]{
        try{
            start_read_loop();//give work to do to each thread
            context.run();
        }catch(...){}
        wss.close(...);//closing the websocket stream, expected to cancel all threads
        context.stop();//with or without it, no change
    });
for(auto& th:pool)
    th.join();//hangs here since the other threads did not return from run()
```

When I want the program to stop, I `close(boost::beast::websocket::close_code::normal,ec)` the stream, which effectively cancels the io operations in the current thread (empty message with error code `boost::beast::websocket::error::closed` received), but not in the other threads : Instead of being cancelled, they hang.

Diving into the code, I eliminated the hypothesis of a deadlock of my own and found that the `context.run()` just didn't notice the websocket stream was closed and continues waiting for an incoming message.

Of course the problem disappears when the pool is limited to a single thread.

calling `close(...)` from outside or inside a io operation does not change the problem.
calling `context.stop()` has no effect either on the problem, be it called outside or inside.

What can be the problem and how am I supposed to make the context stop running on a graceful websocket close ?

================================= EDIT WITH SOLUTION

I managed to change my code thanks to sehe answer above. Instead of starting the read loop in each thread, i'm doing it once after the pool initialization, but adding `auto work=make_work_guard(context);` and `work.reset()`:

```
io_context context;
auto work=make_work_guard(context);//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
std::vector<std::thread> pool(std::thread::hardware_concurrency());
...
wss(make_strand(context),ssl);//I keep it because I will add other streams
...
for(auto& th:pool)
    th=std::thread([&]{
        try{ context.run(); }catch(...){} //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        close_wss_streams_once_each(...);//cancels all threads
    });
start_async_read_loop();//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
work.reset();//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
for(auto& th:pool)
    th.join();
```

Apparently I shouldn't post an IO operation in each thread, which I had decided to do to give all threads work to do. Instead, using the work guqrd prevents the threads from returning prematurely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the same io_context to run a websocket stream

A stream is not a process (or even an operation). You cannot "run a [websocket] stream". You basically only ever run an event loop that executes enqueued handlers, aside from the synchronous code.

> the other threads : Instead of being cancelled, they hang

The code shown begs the opposite question: why don't all the thread **all** immediately return (because no work exists before starting the threads)? It is clear your actual code is sufficiently different for this to not happen.

Perhaps you even have an explicit `work_guard` around. If so, that of course explains why things are not shutting down.

> Of course the problem disappears when the pool is limited to a single thread.

I'm not sure that helps make sense to me. Logically the chances of a deadlock increase with fewer threads. Regardless, that wasn't your problem.

### Imagined Problem Code, But Working

Here's what I imagine, just adding that work-guard to make it so that the threads don't all complete before you even post the first async_read:

```
net::io_context ioc;
std::vector<std::thread> pool(std::thread::hardware_concurrency());

auto work = make_work_guard(ioc);

for (auto& th : pool)
    th = std::thread{[&ioc] { try { ioc.run(); } catch (...) { } }};
```

Now, let's construct, connect, ssl handshake and ws handshake a websocket client (synchronously for simplicity):

```
sctx ctx(sctx::tlsv13_client);
Ws wss(make_strand(ioc), ctx);

auto& s = beast::get_lowest_layer(wss);
s.connect({{}, 8989});
wss.next_layer().handshake(Ws::next_layer_type::handshake_type::client);
wss.handshake("localhost", "/");
```

Now let's add your `loop_read_handler`. Apparently that is some kind of (member) function, but we don't have a class here. So let's drop in a closure:

```
std::function<void(error_code, size_t)> loop_read_handler;

beast::flat_buffer buf;
loop_read_handler = [&](error_code ec, size_t n) {
    std::cout << "loop_read_handler " << ec.message() << ", " << n << std::endl;
    if (n)
        std::cout << "Received " << quoted(beast::buffers_to_string(buf.cdata())) << std::endl;

    if (!ec) {
        buf.consume(n);
        wss.async_read(buf, loop_read_handler);
    }
};
```

Of course, we have to kick off the first read:

```
wss.async_read(buf, loop_read_handler); // not on strand, because nothing is yet on the pool
```

Now, I could do a timer, but realistically you want graceful shutdown when your application receives the signal to terminate, so let's do that for demo:

```
net::signal_set ss(ioc, SIGINT, SIGTERM); // SIGINT e.g. from Ctrl-C in a terminal
ss.async_wait([&](error_code ec, int sig) {
    std::cout << "signal " << ::strsignal(sig) << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
    if (!ec) {
        // on strand:
        post(wss.get_executor(), [&wss] { wss.close(websocket::normal); });
    }
});
```

That's all! Now, all we have to do is wait. So, we can remove the scaffolding:

```
// from this point we're okay returning, as soon as the read loop stops
work.reset();
std::cout << "waiting for graceful shutdown" << std::endl;

for (auto& th : pool)
    th.join();

std::cout << "graceful shutdown complete" << std::endl;
```

### Full Listing

**Live On Coliru**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket/ssl.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
namespace net       = boost::asio;
namespace ssl       = net::ssl;
namespace beast     = boost::beast;
namespace websocket = beast::websocket;

using boost::system::error_code;
using net::ip::tcp;
using sctx = ssl::context;
using Ws   = websocket::stream<ssl::stream<tcp::socket>>;

int main() {
    net::io_context ioc;
    std::vector<std::thread> pool(std::thread::hardware_concurrency());

    auto work = make_work_guard(ioc);

    for (auto& th : pool)
        th = std::thread{[&ioc] { try { ioc.run(); } catch (...) { } }};

    sctx ctx(sctx::tlsv13_client);
    Ws wss(make_strand(ioc), ctx);

    auto& s = beast::get_lowest_layer(wss);
    s.connect({{}, 8989});
    wss.next_layer().handshake(Ws::next_layer_type::handshake_type::client);
    wss.handshake("localhost", "/");

    std::function<void(error_code, size_t)> loop_read_handler;

    beast::flat_buffer buf;
    loop_read_handler = [&](error_code ec, size_t n) {
        std::cout << "loop_read_handler " << ec.message() << ", " << n << std::endl;
        if (n)
            std::cout << "Received " << quoted(beast::buffers_to_string(buf.cdata())) << std::endl;

        if (!ec) {
            buf.consume(n);
            wss.async_read(buf, loop_read_handler);
        }
    };
    wss.async_read(buf, loop_read_handler); // not on strand, because nothing is yet on the pool

    net::signal_set ss(ioc, SIGINT, SIGTERM); // SIGINT e.g. from Ctrl-C in a terminal
    ss.async_wait([&](error_code ec, int sig) {
        std::cout << "signal " << ::strsignal(sig) << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
        if (!ec) {
            // on strand:
            post(wss.get_executor(), [&wss] { wss.close(websocket::normal); });
        }
    });

    // from this point we're okay returning, as soon as the read loop stops
    work.reset();
    std::cout << "waiting for graceful shutdown" << std::endl;

    for (auto& th : pool)
        th.join();

    std::cout << "graceful shutdown complete" << std::endl;
}
```

Running it against a simple demo wss server:

```
websocketd -port 8989 -ssl --sslcert server.pem --sslkey server.pem ping www.google.com
```

And either terminating with Ctrl-C in a terminal, or sending it SIGTERM signal:

[image]

### BONUS

The whole thread pool can be replaced (more correctly!) with `asio::thread_pool`:

```
int main() {
    net::thread_pool ioc;

    // ...
    Ws wss(make_strand(ioc), ctx);

    // ...

    // from this point we're okay returning, as soon as the read loop stops
    std::cout << "waiting for graceful shutdown" << std::endl;
    ioc.join();
    std::cout << "graceful shutdown complete" << std::endl;
}
```

That way, you don't have to meddle with a work-guard at all (or worry about correct handling of exceptions).

Comment: "stream is not a process (or even an operation). You cannot run a [websocket] stream"
certainly I can ```run()``` the io operations of the stream which is of course what I meant.

Thank you for this extensive answer however you are not correct that my code cannot block, indeed all threads start with some ```async_read``` work to do and do it in a loop, which is why they don't return immediately : they are waiting for messages, then repeat doing so

Comment: Indeed I failed to include the start of the read loop in my code above, in each threads before ```run()```, that's my bad. Still the initial issue remains

Comment: Thanks, your actually solved my issue after all, see my answer